# Sort Geospatial Data by Time Posted with Redis

Tags: sorting, redis, geospatial

I'm trying to sort a bunch of data that I get from georadius to be sorted reverse-chronologically based on when the data gets posted. So if I post item1, item3, item2, item4 and they're all within range of the georadius command it should return item4, item2, item3, and item1 regardless of distance. How would I do this with redis's geospatial commands? Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider https://redisearch.io? It is a Redis module that can help you run such queries that filter by Geo and then sort the results

Comment: I actually have it installed right now to use for my search-engine. I'm a little confused though, how could I use RediSearch to look through post time?

Comment: I really only use the autocomplete feature ft.sugadd, ft.sugdel, and ft.sugget. Could you run by me the steps to sort the results of the georadius with RediSearch? In particular the commands used?

Comment: The discord chat is probably a better place than the comments here https://discord.gg/xTbqgTB

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Just sent a message right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to save the post time of each item. For example, you can set a key-value pair for each item, with key as item name, and value as post time.

When you post an item, add it into the GEO structure with geo info, and also record the post time:

1. `GEOADD geo lng lat item1`
2. `SET posttime:item1 timestamp-in-seconds`

When you want to do a search, take the following steps:

1. Use `GEORADIOUS` command with `STORE` option to save the result into a sorted set. Let's name the sorted set as *temp result*.
2. Use the `SORT` command to sort temp result with post time: `SORT temp_result BY posttime:* DESC`